Unsupported Gradle JVM. Your build is currently configured to use Java 18.0.2 and Gradle 4.6
Unsupported Gradle JVM.
Your build is currently configured to use Java 18.0.2 and Gradle 4.6.
Unsupported Gradle JVM.
Your build is currently configured to use Java 18.0.2 and Gradle 4.6.
Unsupported Gradle JVM.
Your build is currently configured to use Java 18.0.2 and Gradle 4.6

Please provide more information.  (Not the same information 4 times.)

According to the Gradle -  Java Compatibility Matrix you need at least Gradle version 7.5 if you want to use Gradle with Java 18. If you need to use Gradle 4.6 you need to install a Java 1.8 version (not recomended, since Java 1.8 is outdated).

You should try to update your gradle, you are in a older version.
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 7.5.1


This version should be compatible with your Java 18.
